# How to remove previously merged branch with master on github

Tags: git, github

So I created a branch and made some changes there and then made a push on my github account and accidentally merge it with master.

Is there a way to undo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roll back to the premerge state.

```
git revert HEAD
```

You can also specify the exact commit/hash/sha.

```
git revert -m 1 f4f78b319c308600eab015a5d6529add21660dc1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Git UI to revert back you merge .Please refer the following link:https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/reverting-a-pull-request
 or you can use the command -->
git reset --hard [commit_before_merge]
where you need to reset the head to the commit just before your current head.